# How would you replace text within a table cell with the text the exact same length?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to alternate a date and a phrase within a `<table>` cell without using fixed width.

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr><th>Date</th></tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr><td id='changethis'>Wed Dec 21 2011</td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

var hold = $('#changethis').text();
setInterval(function () { 
  if ($('#changethis').hasClass("highlight")) { 
    $('#changethis').text(hold);
    $('#changethis').removeClass("highlight");
  }
  else {
    $('#changethis').text(" E  R  R  O  R ");
    $('#changethis').addClass("highlight");
  }
},1000);
```

The problem is the table reformats the width of the column every time the text alternates.  Is it possible to calculate rendered text width and adjust the alternating text accorrdingly??  [JSbin Here](http://jsbin.com/ozunan/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try adding the width to the element

```
$('#changethis').width($('#changethis').width());
```

http://jsbin.com/ozunan/3/edit

Answer (score 0):

to calculate rendered text width:

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(){
    var sensor = $('<div />').css({margin: 0, padding: 0});
    $(this).append(sensor);
    var width = sensor.width();
    sensor.remove();
    return width;
};
```

you can do the rest